# How to determine the amount of binary search trees recursively?

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, catalan

What is a possibility for determining the amount of different binary search trees on a key set of 1,...,n?

Comment: You're gonna need more detail than this. Lay out the problem. What you said doesn't make any sense by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking the total number of binary trees possible with n nodes, well that is [Catalan Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) which is **(2n)!/(n+1)!*n!** .